# Java InputStreams not closing or letting go of file

Tags: java, inputstream

The FileInputStream is not closing when using close().  Wwhen the loop starts back up any files not SFTPd over (due to timeout from server) are inaccessible because it's still holding on the file from the previous loop.  What am I doing wrong when closing the FileInputStream?

Error Text:
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: [Path to File] -> [Path to File]: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Execptions:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.*openDataConnection*(FTPClient.java:920)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.*openDataConnection*(FTPSClient.java:627)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:653)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:639)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:2030)
    at alliedftp.AlliedFtp.putFiles(AlliedFtp.java:73)
    at alliedftp.AlliedFtp.main(AlliedFtp.java:37)

java.nio.file.FileSystemException: [Path to File] -> [Path to File]: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

```
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:387)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)
at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
at alliedftp.AlliedFtp.putFiles(AlliedFtp.java:77)
at alliedftp.AlliedFtp.main(AlliedFtp.java:37)

private static void putFiles(String filePath) {
        AlliedFtp.setPath(filePath);
        FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient();
        String today = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy").format(new Date()) + "_";
while(true) {
            try {
               ArrayList<FileInputStream> list = AlliedFtp.setFileInputStreams(new File(path));
               ArrayList<File> listNames = AlliedFtp.setFileNames(new File(path));
               int fileStreamsSize = list.size();
               int fileNamesSize   = listNames.size();                    
               // Connect to remote host
               client.connect(ftpServer);
               // Login
               if(!client.login(ftpUser, ftpPass)) {
                   client.logout();
                   System.out.println("Login Error");
               } 
               // Enter passive mode
               //client.setBufferSize(1024000);
               client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
               client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
               // SFTP Files
               for(int i = 0; i < fileNamesSize; i++) {     
                    // SFTP files
                    if(client.storeFile(listNames.get(i).getName(), list.get(i))) {
                        // Close input stream
                        list.get(i).close();
                        // Move Files
                        Files.move(listNames.get(i).toPath(), Paths.get(path + File.separator + "Archive" + File.separator + today + listNames.get(i).getName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);   
                    } else {
                        list.get(i).close();
                    }
                }                                
                // Log Out
                client.logout();
                client.disconnect();   
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            } 
            // Wait
            try {
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: sir do you know that `while(true)` creates an infinite loop ?

Comment: I do, the idea was that this would run constantly,  moving files at intervals, which I was trying to accomplish with the TimeUnit.Minutes.sleep(2) (2 is a test value).

Comment: What is `AlliedFtp`? It does not seem to be a public library. Without that knowledge it is difficult to understand how your code is supposed to work.

Comment: AlliedFtp is the name of the class, all of the methods are static.

Comment: I'm not sure, if it is a good idea to create two different `File` objects from the same path. Shouldn't `listNames` contain only names of type `String`? Second: You should safely close the streams in a `finally` block. Third: What happens if there is a _timeout from server_? Exception thrown? please provide the full stack trace.

Comment: Should the finally block be in the for loop?  I've added the exceptions to the post

Comment: Are you sure AlliedFtp is behaving correctly so that the content of list and listNames is in synch with each other?

Comment: @Joakim I'm not, let me check into that